# Unique identifier for every instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm currently trying to save a UIViewController's state easily. However it's obviously possible that there are to controllers of the same class that need to save their data in the same directory.

So I'm looking for a way to get unique identifiers for an instance to write the data safely to the disk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't even make sense. What does it mean for two instances to be "the same after a relaunch of the app"?

Comment: I agree with @KevinBallard, you could phrase the question better. However, I've posted an answer based on my interpretation of how it reads at the minute .

Comment: @KevinBallard updated my question. Hope its better now.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is there is no simple way to do this. Because that's not what you're supposed to be doing. Object instances are not a data model. Linkages between objects are not saved between runs. However, identifiers for *data* can be created, and objects can keep track of those identifiers, and corresponding linkages between data.

e.g. You can create linkages between objects in your data model, by assigning a UUIDs when you create an instance, and then saving that to disk when you quit... loading it from disk when you launch.

I'd look into NSCoding and Core Data... they're both designed to allow you to persist your data when you quit your app.

Perhaps update/ask a new question, clarifying what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: The problem about core data is that I still need an identifier to find the proper nsmanagedobject.

Comment: @Larcus94 wouldn't `NSManagedObject`'s `objectID` property do the trick? If you're trying to save and restore relationships between objects, CoreData will do that nicely.

Comment: Hmm how would I do it then? I still need to store the objectID somewhere so I find the NSManagedObject again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I've read your question correctly, but I did read it twice.

Is this what you need?

#### MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    int myID;
}
@end
```

#### MyClass.m

```
//this is where the magic is. Keeps a static identifier which starts at zero each time you start the app and increments each time you init this class.
static int identifier = 0;

@implementation MyClass

-(id) init
    ...

    identifier ++;
    myID = identifier;
    ...
}
....
@end
```

Comment: This works, except it wouldn't be the same next launch. Static int doesn't persist between sessions.

Comment: True that. Would be an easy way but it won't be the same after a restart of the app.

Comment: It seems I did read your question wrongly. It would be the work assuming you create the instances in the same order but if you can't guarantee that, my answer will not work.